# iPhone NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBounds :CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70)];
```

After increasing navigationBar's height, how can I vertically center the left- and rightBarButtonItem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just create a UIView and add a UILabel in it, then add that UIView as a subview to the navigationBar.(Add the UIView in the center)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the *vertical* center?

You can't do this in an easy/supported way, since the extra space on top of the UINavigationBar is intended for help text and not to simply be a taller view. Consider redesigning your center view layout to deal with the fact that UINavigationBar is meant to be a fixed size.